# How do I resolve line outlines jutting into other lines in Mapnik/Cascadenik

Tags: cartography, openstreetmap, mapnik

We are designing a basemap, and I am trying to resolve a problem with outlines that comes up in roads. The idea is to have lighter colors roads, but they don't get pushed out far enough with our light background. I've tried various combinations of outline-cap and outline-join, but still run into tiny outlines sticking into the joints of lines/roads.

is there something I am missing to resolve this, or should i just choose a color that stands out above the land?

Comment: could you attach an image showing the problem, please?

Answer (score 2):

This excellent blog post goes into good detail and explains your issue.

*"The standard style of rendering roads, with labels placed inside light-colored fills and a thin outline on the edges, is accomplished by repeating layers. First, you put down a layer of thick, dark-colored roads, for example 14 pixels wide. Second, you put down another layer of thinner, light-colored roads, for example 12 pixels wide. The combination of the two yields correctly-outlined street grids, without the woven appearance of street intersections where it looks as though one road is covering another. A lot complicated visual effects can be achieved in similar ways, with repetition and layering to build up a particular effect."*

http://mike.teczno.com/notes/mapnik.html

with images and other good links, **read the whole post** to get a better sense of the layer management process.